# Mongo ISODate query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have a mongo query to be executed :

```
query = { "dateField" : { "$gte" : ISODate('2011-11-10T07:45:32.962Z')  } }
```

When I do a `db.Collection.find(query)` on the mongo shell, I am able to retrieve the results.

How could I query this using Java ? I tried constructing a String based on the Date parameter.
But in the process of building the String, it eventually gets passed as `"ISODate('2011-11-10T07:45:32.962Z')"` instead of `ISODate('2011-11-10T07:45:32.962Z')` (without the surrounding quotes).

What would be the best way to construct this query using the Java API ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do not use strings. Strings are not dates.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use a regular Java Date--also I recommend the QueryBuilder:

```
Date d = new Date(); // or make a date out of a string...
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start().put("dateField").greaterThanEquals(d).get();
```

Comment: Yes, that's the Java equivalent of ISODate(). Try running the query, rather than looking at the toString().

Answer (score 7):

I have search lot and spend more than hour in finding how to get data when  having `ISODate` in mongo model.

As the default constructor for date is deprecated so it was not working in my case.

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("_id" , 1);
try {
        searchQuery.append("timestamp",BasicDBObjectBuilder.start( "$gte",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'").parse("2015-12-07T10:38:17.498Z")).get());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment? If it's an answer, please [edit] it to clarify how it addresses the question.

Comment: This is answer, I am telling that the simple `Date` not works as it is deprecated and this thing `SimpleDateFormat` was working fine in my case.